# 'tuple' object does not support item assignment - DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have a dictionary `d` of data frames, where the keys are the names and the values are the actual data frames. I have a function that normalizes some of the data frame and spits out a plot, with the title. The function takes in a tuple from `d.items()` (as the parameter `df`) so the first (0th) element is the name and the next is the data frame.

I have to do some manipulations on the data frame in the function, and I do so using `df[1]` without any issues. However, one line is `df[1] = df[1].round(2)` and this throws the error `'tuple' object does not support item assignment`. I have verified that `df[1]` is a data frame by printing out its type write before this line. Why doesn't this work? It's not a tuple.

Comment: Show the sample code please to reproduce this problem

Answer (score 1):

That's because your variable is a tuple and you can't assign to a tuple. Tuples are immutable. My understanding of your question:

```
from pandas import DataFrame

d    = {'mydf' : DataFrame({'c1':(1,2),'c2':(4,5)}) } #A dictionary of DFs. 
i    = list(d.items())[0]                             #The first item from .items()
i[1] = i[1].round(2)                                  #ERROR
```

Notice that "i" is a tuple, because that is what .items() returns (tuples). You can't save to i, even if what you are overwriting is something that is mutable. I know that this sounds strange, because you can do things like this:

```
x = (7,[1,2,3])
x[1].append(4)
print(x)
```

The reason this works is complicated. Essentially the tuples above are storing the pointers to the information within the tuples (not the data themselves). Hence, if  you access a tuple's item (like x[1]), then python takes you to that pointers item (in my case a list) and allows you to run append on it, because the list is mutable. In your case, you are not trying to access the i[1] all by itself, you are trying to overwrite the i[1] entry in the tuple. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: But I printed out the type of df[1] write before the line. It is a DataFrame. df is a tuple, df[0] is the name, df[1] is the dataframe.

Comment: Right. Just like if I printed x[1] it would be a list. But I still can't save to x[1], because that would be saving to the tuple x. I can update x[1] with something like append, but I can't save to x[1]. I can pull the list out of the tuple, like y = x[1]. Now y is not in the tuple, so now I can run " y = y + [1] " and overwrite y, because I am not saving to the tuple.